# SQL column update with a calculation

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I update the values in SQL column using multiplication and then divide it again?

Values of column "price" need to be updated with "price" multiplied by 1.08 and then "price" divide by 1.077

Thanks a lot for the help
Andreas

Comment: What is your actual question, and what is stopping you from just doing this math on the column?

Comment: Well, because my query is not working ;-), 

UPDATE `products_price` * 1.08 / 1.077 WHERE `products_tax_class_id`=1;

that up there was my idea of doing the math in the column. So the values of the column "products_price" need to be muliplied and divided when products_tax_class_id = 1

Comment: What is your query?  If you have a question about a query, it usually helps if you share the query.

Answer (score 1):

Simply chain the arithmetic:

```
update t
    set price = price * 1.08 / 1.077;
```

Multiplication and division can be done in the same operation.